# Formula issue getting #value

Tags: excel-formula, formulas

Hi to anyone that can help. Please find below a copy of a simple formula.

For some reason I am getting `#VALUE` on this formula and I cannot for the life see why. I think I need a new set of eyes to view this.

Can someone please spot any errors?

```
=IF(E2="Follow-up",(TODAY()-F2)/7),IF(E2="Identify",(TODAY()-C2/7),"Not Applicable")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=IF(E2="Follow-up",((TODAY()-F2)/7),IF(E2="Identify",((TODAY()-C2)/7),"Not Applicable"))
```

It was missing some brackets in these sections: `((TODAY()-F2)/7)`

Comment: Thank you @CallumDA. Indeed it was.

Comment: No problem, feel free to accept or upvote answers that help